# Find unique list of tuples irrespective of order inside tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, tuples

Given input:

```py
[('is','my','order'), ('my','order', 'is'), ('temp', 'ques'), ('ques','temp')]
```

Desired output:

```py
[('is','my','order'), ('temp', 'ques')]
```

In the output, the order of the tuple or the order of the contents of tuple doesn't matter.

Comment: If their order doesn't matter maybe consider using `set`s the first place (rather than tuples).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because for you order doesn't matter, you can use `set` to achieve this:

```
>>> input_list = [('is','my','order'), ('my','order', 'is'), ('temp', 'ques'), ('ques','temp')]

>>> set(tuple(sorted(l)) for l in input_list)
set([('ques', 'temp'), ('is', 'my', 'order')])
```

Firstly sort the content of each nested tuple to ensure your set considers tuples with common items as same. Then I am type-casting it again to `tuple` because `sorted` returns `list` which are unhashable. Finally, `set` removes duplicate entries of your tuples.

Please refer ["set" documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) for more details.

Comment: Only here there can be options that are not in the initial data

Answer (score 0):

You can sort each of the sublists and then add them to a list, dropping all duplicates

```
output_list = []
for tup in map(sorted, tuple_list):
  if tup not in output_list:
    output_list.append(tup)
print(output_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mytuples = [('one','two'), ('two','one)]
myset=set()
for x in mytuples:
    myset.update(x)

print(myset)
output {'two', 'one'}
```

this will give you a set of all the unique values in your dataset.  maybe not helpful

so you may have to check each tuple against every other tuple with the same length assuming you want to keep the tuple structure